# Unable to open PNG file to convert to TIFF via ImageMagick

Tags: visual-studio-2010, imagemagick, 32bit-64bit, imagemagick-convert

I am using ImageMagick 6.6.6. My code base is in VS10 c++. I have been able to compile my code in both 64bit and 32 bit exe with respective libraries of ImageMagik. When I run my 32bit exe the conversion from PNG to TIFF works fine.But when I run 64bit exe it throws exception saying :
"reason 0x0000000009eae030 "UnableToOpenFile `\du\TEST\tiff\IMG\1.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3759"

Futher debugging I came across that problem is with
 "readImages( &tif, sourceFile )" which is throwing error 
"exceptionInfo.severity FileOpenError   MagickCore::ExceptionType error_number=0".

PNGs are not corrupted and opens fine.Permission for exes running are same. And input and output file locations are also in same system.

Where I could be possibly be wrong or missing  ? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: There is no ImageMagick 4.9.2. Please check again. `convert -version`. Did you install the proper bit-depth install of ImageMagick on each system?

Comment: Hi fmw42 sorry I am using version 6.6.6. I am using magick++APIs in my code. I am not using command line ImageMagik. Thanks for your response.

Comment: IM 6.6.x is ancient -- over 400 versions old. Perhaps you should consider upgrading.

Comment: @fmw42 I just wanted to know 1.what is meaning of "exceptionInfo.severity  = FileOpenError" 2. in error "UnableToOpenFile `s\\dubeyris\\test\\64bit\\tiff\TiffService\\1.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3759" should I be seeing complete path?? `s\\dubeyris\\test\\64bit\\tiff\TiffService\\1.png' is a partial path shown in error.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know why you only see part of the path. Seems like your PNG is corrupt or libpng may not support your 64-bit version or such an old version of IM may not support 64-bit systems. Sorry, I do not code in C or C++, so cannot advise on errors in coding or compile. What is the date of your IM version `convert -version` should show that. Also what platform?

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 . Will look into it